# Filtering out rows of a table bassed on a column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, filtering

I am trying to filter out table `rows` based in column `value`.

I have a `dataframe`:

```
+---+-----+
|id |value|
+---+-----+
|3  |0    |
|3  |1    |
|3  |0    |
|4  |1    |
|4  |0    |
|4  |0    |
+---+-----+
```

I want to create a new `dataframe` deleting all `rows` with `value!=0`:

```
+---+-----+
|id |value|
+---+-----+
|3  |0    |
|3  |0    |
|4  |0    |
|4  |0    |
+---+-----+
```

I figured the syntax should be something like this but couldn't get it right:

```
val newDataFrame = OldDataFrame.filter($"value"==0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct way is as following. You just forgot to add one = sign

```
val newDataFrame = OldDataFrame.filter($"value" === 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Their are various ways by which you can do the filtering.

1. `val newDataFrame = OldDataFrame.filter($"value"===0)`
2. `val newDataFrame = OldDataFrame.filter(OldDataFrame("value") === 0)`
3. `val newDataFrame = OldDataFrame.filter("value === 0")`

You can also use `where` function as well instead of `filter`.